# How do I detect when a user unmutes a video in swift when using AVPlayer

Tags: swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am trying to determine if a user taps on the unmute button while watching a video. I am aware of player.isMuted but I am not sure how to check if there is a change if value. I am using AVPlayerVideoViewController and want to override the unmute button functionality.
[image: This is the button I want to detect if it is tapped or not]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a sample ViewController, you can observe `isMuted` changes easily:

```swift
import AVKit

class ViewController: AVPlayerViewController {
    var muteObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let videoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: "mov") else {
            return
        }

        let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        player?.play()
        
        muteObservation = player?.observe(\.isMuted) { player, _ in
            print("isMuted: \(player.isMuted)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sash Is this answers your question?